# How to specify projects in MSBUILD and imitate what Publish Website at VS2008 is doing

Tags: vb.net, msbuild

Below is the build after right-clicking the Website and Publish Website

```
 

    ------ Build started: Project: Company.CIO.BIA.GTE.DomainModel.Interface, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
    Company.CIO.BIA.GTE.DomainModel.Interface -> C:\CIO-BIA\GTE\Development\Codes\Business Layer\Company.CIO.BIA.GTE.DomainModel.Interface\bin\Debug\DomainModel.Interface.dll
    ------ Build started: Project: Company.CIO.BIA.GTE.DataAccess, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
    Company.CIO.BIA.GTE.DataAccess -> C:\CIO-BIA\GTE\Development\Codes\Data Access Layer\Company.CIO.BIA.GTE.DataAccess\bin\Debug\DataAccess.dll
    ------ Build started: Project: Company.CIO.BIA.GTE.DomainModel, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
    Company.CIO.BIA.GTE.DomainModel -> C:\CIO-BIA\GTE\Development\Codes\Business Layer\Company.CIO.BIA.GTE.DomainModel\bin\Debug\DomainModel.dll
    ------ Build started: Project: Main.Interface, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
    Main.Interface -> C:\CIO-BIA\GTE\Development\Codes\Main.Interface\bin\Debug\Main.Interface.dll
    ------ Skipped Build: Project: Main, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
    Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
    ------ Build started: Project: C:\...\Company.CIO.BIA.GTE\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
    Pre-compiling Web Site

    Building directory '/Company.CIO.BIA.GTE/App_Code/'.
    Building directory '/Company.CIO.BIA.GTE/Errors/'.
    Building directory '/Company.CIO.BIA.GTE/Shared/'.
    Building directory '/Company.CIO.BIA.GTE/Main/'.
    Building directory '/Company.CIO.BIA.GTE/UserControl/'.
    Building directory '/Company.CIO.BIA.GTE/Scripts/JQuery/CLEditor/'.
    Building directory '/Company.CIO.BIA.GTE/Scripts/JQuery/'.
    Building directory '/Company.CIO.BIA.GTE/Scripts/'.
    Pre-compilation Complete
    ------ Publish started: Project: C:\...\Company.CIO.BIA.GTE\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
    Connecting to site C:\CIO-BIA\GTE\Development\Codes\PrecompiledWeb\Company.CIO.BIA.GTE...
    Deleting existing files...
    Publishing directory /...
    Publishing directory App_Themes...
    Publishing directory App_Themes/Default...
    Publishing directory bin...
    Publishing directory Errors...
    Publishing directory Images...
    Publishing directory Main...
    Publishing directory Scripts...
    Publishing directory Scripts/JQuery...
    Publishing directory Scripts/JQuery/CLEditor...
    Publishing directory Scripts/JQuery/CLEditor/images...
    Publishing directory Shared...
    Publishing directory SiteMap...
    Publishing directory Styles...
    Publishing directory UserControl...
    Publishing directory WebService...
    Publishing directory WebService/Batch...
    ========== Build: 5 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========
    ========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don't want to build the whole solution just those projects that are built at Publish Website method in Visual Studio..

What would be its equivalent MSBUILD command? Aside from assigning a build configuration.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *project* name instead of a *solution* name in the command line. But for that to work, the project must have the configuration defined, it can't just depend on the configs at the solution level. Use the Configuration Manager to create project-level configs if needed. The rest of the parameters are fairly well documented.